# Visual studio 2010 ultimate error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When i open a new project and select console application i get an error message

The name of a property stored under the registry key HKEY_local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\MSBUild\ToolsVersions\4.0 has zero length

can anyone shoe how to solve this problem. I reinstalled many times

Comment: Did you reinstall the .NET framework or just VS2010?

Comment: complete software i reinstalled

Comment: registration clen up should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can clean up your registry....try using ccleaner and clean up ur registry